# MiniMax algorithm not smart after added depth

Tags: java, algorithm, artificial-intelligence, tic-tac-toe, minimax

Tic-tac-toe game, the AI class is not smart enough to be unbeatable.

AI class is supposed to calculate the best spot given a tic-tac-toe board. The 'getBestSpot' method calls min-max until the game ends. A gameState class is being used to check the status of the game and get the winner.

The board is cloned with a copy constructor so the actual board's properties are not modified. Then it gets the available spots in the copied board and it plays in each of them. It keeps doing this until the game ends and then it scores the played spot given the 'depth' and the outcome:

Case score:

- win = 1 - depth
- lose = -1 - depth
- tie = 0 - depth

'Object[]' is being used to pass both 'int bestSpot, String bestSpot' between min-max. It will be refactored to use 'int[]' instead.

After some research, it was advised to add depth as it could help in case the scores of each available spot were the same. After adding depth, the more turns it takes to play this position, the less score it will have but it still fails to return the best spot.

In this case, the opponents token is `O` and AI(`X`) should play in spot `0` to minimize/prevent Opponent(`O`) from winning, spot `0` should get the highest score because if AI(`X`) doesn't play there Opponent(`O`) will, and that makes the other available spots have less score because the getScore() returns `-1 - depth` when the opponent wins. Failing test:

```
@Test
public void testMinimizedSpotCaseLosing() {
    newGrid = new String[]{"0", "O", "X",
                           "O", "X", "5",
                           "O", "7", "8"};
    board.setGrid(newGrid);
    assertEquals( "0", miniMax.minimizedSpot(board, 0)[0] );
}


Test output:

    junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: 
    Expected :0
    Actual   :5
```

Here is the AI class:

```
public class AI {

    private String token;
    private GameState gameState;
    private String opponentToken;

    AI(String token) {
        this.token = token;
        gameState = new GameState();
        opponentToken = null;

        setOpponentToken();
    }


    public String getToken() {
        return token;
    }

    public String getOpponentToken() {
        return opponentToken;
    }

    public void setOpponentToken() {
        if(token.equals("X")) {
            opponentToken = "O";
        } else {
            opponentToken = "X";
        }
    }

    public int getBestSpot(Board board) {
        String[] grid = board.getGrid();
        if( !grid[4].equals("X") && !grid[4].equals("O")) {
            return 4;
        } else {
            return Integer.parseInt((String) maximizedSpot(board, 0)[0]);
        }
    }

    public Object[] maximizedSpot(Board board, int depth) {
        Board boardClone = new Board(board);

        int bestScore = 0;
        String bestSpot = null;
        int score;

        String[] availableSpots = boardClone.getAvailableSpots();

        for(String availableSpot: availableSpots) {
            int spot = Integer.parseInt(availableSpot);
            boardClone.setSpot(spot, token);
            depth += 1;

            if( gameState.finished(boardClone) ) {
                score = getScore(boardClone, depth);
            } else {
                Object[] minimizedSpot = minimizedSpot(boardClone, depth);
                score = (int) minimizedSpot[1];
            }
            boardClone.setGrid(board.getGrid());

            if( bestScore == 0 || score > bestScore ) {
                bestScore = score;
                bestSpot = availableSpot;
            }

        }
        return new Object[]{bestSpot, bestScore};
    }

    public Object[] minimizedSpot(Board board, int depth) {
        Board boardClone = new Board(board);

        int bestScore = 0;
        String bestSpot = null;
        int score;


        String[] availableSpots = boardClone.getAvailableSpots();

        for(String availableSpot: availableSpots) {
            int spot = Integer.parseInt(availableSpot);
            boardClone.setSpot(spot, opponentToken);
            depth += 1;

            if ( gameState.finished(boardClone) ) {
                score = getScore(boardClone, depth);
            } else {
                Object[] maximizedSpot = maximizedSpot(boardClone, depth);
                score = (int) maximizedSpot[1];
            }
            boardClone.setGrid(board.getGrid());

            if (bestScore == 0 || score < bestScore) {
                bestScore = score;
                bestSpot = availableSpot;
            }
        }
        return new Object[]{bestSpot, bestScore};
    }

    public int getScore(Board board, int depth) {
        if( gameState.finished(board) && gameState.getWinnerToken() != null ) {
            String winnerToken = (gameState.getWinnerToken());
            if(winnerToken.equals(token)) {
                return 1 - depth;
            } else if (winnerToken.equals(opponentToken)) {
                return -1 - depth;
            }
        }
        return 0 - depth;
    }
}
```

Board class

```
public class Board {

private String[] grid;
private int[][] winCombinations;

public Board() {
    this.grid = new String[]{"0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"};
    this.winCombinations = new int[][]{{0,1,2}, {3,4,5}, {6,7,8}, {0,3,6}, {1,4,7,}, {2,5,8}, {0,4,8}, {2,4,6}};
}

public Board(Board sourceBoard) {
    this();
    System.arraycopy(sourceBoard.grid, 0, this.grid, 0, sourceBoard.grid.length);

    for (int i = 0; i < winCombinations.length; i++) {
        int[] line = winCombinations[i];
        System.arraycopy(sourceBoard.winCombinations[i], 0, line, 0, line.length);
    }
}

public String[] getGrid() {
    return grid;
}

public int[][] getWinCombinations() {
    return winCombinations;
}

public String[] getAvailableSpots() {
    ArrayList<String> resultList = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (String aGrid : grid) {
        if (!aGrid.equals("X") && !aGrid.equals("O")) {
            resultList.add(aGrid);
        }
    }
    return resultList.toArray(new String[resultList.size()]);
}

public void reset() {
    grid = new String[]{"0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"};
}

public void setSpot(int i, String token) {
    grid[i] = token;
}

public void setGrid(String[] grid) {
    this.grid = grid;
}

}
```

GameState class:

```
public class GameState {

private String winner;

public GameState() {
    this.winner = null;
}

public boolean checkTie(Board board) {
    String[] availableSpots = board.getAvailableSpots();

    return availableSpots.length == 0 && !checkWin(board);
}

public boolean checkWin(Board board) {
    int[][] winCombinations = board.getWinCombinations();
    String[] grid = board.getGrid();

    for (int[] winCombination : winCombinations) {
        boolean combinationState = checkWinCombination(winCombination, board);

        if (combinationState) {
            // Get token inside winCombination and set to winner variable.
            setWinnerToken(grid[winCombination[0]]);
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public boolean checkWinCombination(int[] combination, Board board) {
    String[] grid = board.getGrid();
    return grid[combination[0]].equals("X") && grid[combination[1]].equals("X") && grid[combination[2]].equals("X") || grid[combination[0]].equals("O") && grid[combination[1]].equals("O") && grid[combination[2]].equals("O");
}

public boolean finished(Board board) {
    return checkWin(board) || checkTie(board);
}

public String getWinnerToken() {
    return winner;
}

public void setWinnerToken(String token) {
    winner = token;
}
}
```

Comment: Could you explain the game? at first, it looks like tic-tac-toe, but the numbers on the board confuse me. Also, could you explain, why you return an `Object[]` from `minimizedSpot(...)` and how the expected value of `"0"` is calculated?

Comment: Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: It seems like you are trying to implement a Tic Tac Toe Player using the min-max algorithm in Java. Here is a solution on the Web: https://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/JavaGame_TicTacToe_AI.html . Does this help?

Comment: @Turing85 minimizedSpot method plays with the opponents token and maximizedSpot method plays with the AI's token. Each method plays in each available spot until the game is finished. When finished, it gives a score to that spot. In this case, it should return `0` as it is the position that the opponent would play to 'win' and finish the game. I've edited the post.

Comment: @Prune Added missing code to reproduce the problem, description of how it works with explained example.